# Python Pool.map() is not terminating but only in debug mode

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is not the first time I have problems with `Pool()` while trying to debug something.

Please note, that I do *not* try to debug the code which is paralellized. I want to debug code which gets executed much later. The problem is, that this code is never reached and the cause for this is that `pool.map()` is not terminating.

I have created a simple pipeline which does a few things. Among those things is a very simple preprocessing step for textual data.

To speed things up I am running:

```
print('Preprocess text')
with Pool() as pool:
    df_preprocessed['text'] = pool.map(preprocessor.preprocess, df.text)
```

But here is the thing:

For some reason this code runs only *one* time. The second time I am ending up in an endless loop in `_handle_workers()` of the `pool.py` module:

```
@staticmethod
def _handle_workers(pool):
    thread = threading.current_thread()

    # Keep maintaining workers until the cache gets drained, unless the pool
    # is terminated.
    while thread._state == RUN or (pool._cache and thread._state != TERMINATE):
        pool._maintain_pool()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    # send sentinel to stop workers
    pool._taskqueue.put(None)
    util.debug('worker handler exiting')
```

Note the `while`-loop. My script simply ends up there when calling my preprocessing function a second time.

**Please note:** This *only happens during a debugging session*! If the script is executed without a debugger everything is working fine.

What could be the reason for this?

---

#### Environment

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

---

#### Update

This could be a known bug

- [infinite waiting in multiprocessing.Pool](https://bugs.python.org/issue34781)

Comment: You’re using pdb as the debugger?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Hm, that's a good question. I am using PyCharm which uses a miniconda environment (Python 3.5.6) - not quite sure which debugger it's using.

Comment: Have you tried the expert programmer’s diagnostic technique, slapping print statements everywhere?

Comment: Which OS? Do you recreate the Pool for the second time or are you using the existing one?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes - first weapon of choice: Highly sophisticated standard output signal debugging. I am pretty sure it's [this suspected bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue34781) by now. Calling `print()` in `preprocess()` (first line) reveals that it's running for the first time but the second time it's just not getting executed anymore. So `pool.map()` does "nothing".

Comment: @Darkonaut Ubuntu 16.04 and yes. The pool gets created a second time. Re-using the old one is not possible since this happens inside a member function of an object (let's call it `PreprocessTask`).

Comment: Have a try with `multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")` then, might be a forking issue with the debugger.